# How to avoid restart of a third-party installer under Inno Setup?

Tags: deployment, installation, inno-setup, device-driver

I'm using [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup), and I need to install a third-party driver. Everything is OK, except that this third-party installation program asks to restart the machine, before my installation script terminate.

Example: I need to install two drivers, the second need the first installed, but the first driver needs to restart the machine.

```
[Run]

Filename: "FirstDriver.msi"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; 
Filename: "SecondDriver.msi"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated;
```

I'd like to restart only my installation is complete. How can I do it?

Comment: Unless the third-party installers accept command-line arguments to avoid requiring the machine to be restarted, I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Hum... I did it in command line : `msiexec /package "FirstDriver.msi" /qf /norestart`, but I wasn't sucessfull when I try it with Inno Setup.

Comment: I tried it in Run section: `Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/package ""{app}\FirstDriver.msi"" /qf /norestart "; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated;`

Comment: But it seems [`it should work`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @TLama due to the complexity of MSI packages (especially custom actions created by everyone), a general approach such as adding `/norestart` won't work every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
Filename: "{sys}\msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/package ""{app}\FirstDriver.msi"" /qn /norestart /passive"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode; StatusMsg: "Installing my First Driver";
```

I needed to specify that directory of msiexec.exe to work, using the constant `{sys}`, to get msiexec.exe from System folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the third-party installers with the `/norestart` command-line argument:

```
[Run]

Filename: "FirstDriver.msi"; Parameters: /norestart; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated; 
Filename: "SecondDriver.msi"; Parameters: /norestart; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated;
```

**Edit**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558882/msi-silent-without-rebooting-automatically) question for more details.

Comment: You can't always pass parameters when using `ShellExecute()` to run a non executable. It may not get translated when the final command is created or if it uses DDE to talk to an existing process.